# Entity Framework - Timeout during debugging (cannot open provider error)?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

During debugging my services code with uses Entity Framework for Oracle, I find that if I pause a little too long while examining code, the next time the connection is needed (I have a single context open during the entire transaction) I get an error stating that the provider could not be opened.  Is there some sort of timeout in EF or the connection pool that I'm hitting?  How can I tell and/or fix it?

Comment: You can change `Connection Timeout` in the connection string, or `Connection Lifetime`. It probably depends on where your breakpoint is (with or without an open connection). Does the Oracle provider use connection pooling?

Comment: I do believe it does use connection pooling.  I know that the connection timeout can be modified, but I'm not getting a connection timeout error explicitly.  I just lose access to the context after a period of time.  It could be related to a connection timeout.  I was wondering if anyone else ran into this.

Comment: Did you get that working? I'm getting this weirdness when working with EF against Sql Server. When I wait a bit, I get error messages but not if I just step through quickly...

Comment: @GertArnold I'm getting similar misbehavior against Sql Server. Could you elaborate on the settings you're discussing, please? I'm not exactly SQL savvy and "*The underlying provider failed on Open*" is very cryptic (despite googling by behind off). It'd be awesome if I learned how to get rid of this stupid issue.